# Creating a file of a certain type with Real Studio

Tags: editor, file-type, realbasic

I am making an editor with Real Studio for a special kind of file type. I made the file type with the File Type Editor, but how can I make a file output stream for that file type? Currently I am using:

```
DIM f AS FolderItem
DIM t AS TextOutputStream
f = GetFolderItem(fileName)
t = TextOutputStream.Create(f)
t.Write theData
t.Close
```

But that doesn't create a file openable by my editor. I am looking for something like this:

```
DIM f AS FolderItem
DIM t As FileTypes1.MyFileType.OutputStream
f = GetFolderItem(fileName)
t = FileTypes1.MyFileType.OutputStream.Create(f)
t.Write theData
t.Close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added this to my code:

```
f.MacCreator = FileTypes1.MyFileType.MacCreator
f.MacType = FileTypes1.MyFileType.MacType
```

so that my application recognizes the files.

Answer (score 1):

The TextOutputStream will only create text.  You'll need to find out what the format definition is of type you're trying to create and duplicate it using the BinaryStream.  More information about the BinaryStream can be found at http://docs.realsoftware.com/index.php/BinaryStream.